# AWS Airflow v2.0.2 doesn't show Postgres connection type

Tags: postgresql, airflow, mwaa

I just started migrating my Airflow v2.0.2 codebase to MWAA (AWS Airflow service). I added the following to the requirements.txt (and uploaded it to the S3 bucket intended for sync):

```
apache-airflow-providers-postgres==2.0.0
```

But Postgres connection type doesn't show up in the new connection UI:

[image]

What's going on here and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with MWAA (currently). It does not install Postgres provider in webserver currently. From what I know, this might be solved in the future, but for now I believe the only solution is to define connection manually via secret manager https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html